# How can I trace the source of HTML from a div while using a tool such as FireBug so that I can alter it in the backend?

Tags: php, html, templates, firebug, buddypress

I recognize this may be a very fundamental question to ask.  I'm very new to this.

...but for example.  I inspect the 'questions' button here on stackoverflow. It shows me:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body class="ask-page">
        <noscript><div id="noscript-padding"></div></noscript>
        <div id="notify-container"></div>
        <div id="overlay-header"></div>
        <div id="custom-header"></div>
        <div class="container">
         <div id="header">
         <div id="portalLink">
         <div id="topbar">
         <br class="cbt">
         <div id="hlogo">
         <div id="hmenus">
             <div class="nav mainnavs">
              <ul>
               <li>
                <a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a>
               </li>
```

How do i figure out where this is being applied to the site in the backend?  What template or file would I be looking for?  I'm working with BuddyPress specifically.  They use .php templates.  But I have no clue of the source just by looking at a div's css/html via FireBug.

Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: can't be answered. literally you'll just have to figure out where in your site's template the relevant html is being generated. yes, it's ugly, but that's the price of using a template engine. you lose any real sense of where anything happens, as well as the ability to easily say "line X of the html is generated at line Y in template Z".... not without embedding tons of debug comments in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell which template generated the HTML by looking only at the HTML.

If a page has some unique text on it, you *might* be able to tell which php file generated that text by using `grep`.  But a lot of templating software stores almost *all* the text for a web page in a database. Text in database isn't exposed to `grep`.

Since WordPress stores almost *all* a site's text in a database, you'll have to work a little harder.  I suggest starting with [WordPress fundamentals](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wordpress-fundementals-for-newbies).  Since you're essentially a user in this scenario, look hard at themes first.  In the WordPress architecture of core, plugins, and themes, themes "sit" closer to the user than core and plugins.

Don't miss StackExchange's [Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes just use the find function in my editing software. It is available in most major programs such as Visual studio and Dreamweaver and will search through any number of files in a folder to find your tag.

Answer (score 0):

To get what is the right theme file to edit to get the differences I usually search for something that is supposed to be just in that page, such as a div with a particular ID or a script.

Also I use a Firebug extension called "Firediff" that allows me to keep trace of all the changes I do in the HTML or CSS, so I can reproduce them: [firediff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firediff/)